# Tableau Calculated field based on month

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I am trying to create a calculation in Tableau as I have in excel. I could do first half of it, but not sure how to give the condition for months. Below is how my raw data looks like.

`ID       Month    CASE_STATUS   CASE_TYPE`
`1011   2/1/2016    Closed       Group1`
`1012   2/1/2016    Closed       Group2`
`1013   3/1/2016    Open         Group1`
`1014   3/1/2016    Closed       Group3`
`1015   3/1/2016    Closed       Group3`
`1016   4/1/2016    Unkwn        Group1`
`1017   4/1/2016    Closed       Group7`
`1018   4/1/2016    Closed       Group5`
`1019   4/1/2016    Closed       Group4`
`1020   2/1/2016    Open         Group1`
`1021   3/1/2016    Closed       Group1`
`1022   4/1/2016    Closed       Group2`
`1023   4/1/2016    Uknwn        Group1`
`1024   2/1/2016    Closed       Group4`
`1025   2/1/2016    Closed       Group5`
`1026   2/1/2016    Closed       Group2`
`1027   3/1/2016    Closed       Group3`

I want to create a reference line that adds all ID's (sum of count of ID's) divide by 13 for Feb, Mar and April. This reference line will start from May and be constant for the year

`field1:
IIF(
(month([Fiscal Month]) >1) and (month([Fiscal Month]) <5  and (year([Fiscal Month]) = 2016)) , 1,0)`

`field2:
if sum([field1]) > 1
then round(div((count[ID]),13))
else 0
end`

But this does not give me the reference line I am looking for.

**I have an example image, but not sure how could I insert that here.**

Comment: what's the purpose of it? Why do you calculate =sum($E3:$E5)/13 twice? Do you always want to add up the latest 3 months? Or is it hard coded always these 3 months? What kind of line do you expect and what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: This is calculation I am using to get a reference line. the reason it is shown twice is because, once I calculate the value using feb, mar and april month, I will be using that value to show the ref line starting may for a year

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a pretty hard coded solution and for that you could just use a constant but this might help to get you started and maybe you do it dynamically later.

This is assuming that you always want to add Feb, Mar and Apr to get your reference line.

Create the `[Grand Total]` field with `[Group1] + [Group2] + [Group3]`

Create a calculated field with

```
SUM(
  IIF(
    [month] > '2016-01-31' AND [month] < '2016-05-01', 
    [Grand Total],
    0)
   ) / 13
```

call it `[Reference Line]`

Drag the new field onto the Details shelf, go to analytics and drag a Reference line into your graph, now you can select the new measure as the source for the reference line and it should appear with the calculated value.

If this is not what you want, it would be helpful to share a screenshot of your Tableau window and maybe a mock up of what you would like to display.

Comment: Hi Alexander..thanks for the solution. I tried it, but I do not have a Grand Total field in my table. Is there a way that I could create it in Tableau? (may be another calculated field to pull in this one?) How do I create this grand total field for Feb, Mar and April?

Comment: added the calculation for Grand Total. It calculates it for every month and filters in the second calculation to only use these 3 months for the reference line. If you want the Grand Total only calculated for those 3 months, just use the IIF() from the other formula and instead of [Grand Total] use the addition from the first formula

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I will try this and let know how it goes.

Comment: It gives error "Cannot mix Aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function".